# Download/Export HeatMap ngx swimlane chart as image

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

Download/Export HeatMap ngx swimlane char as image.

Refer plunker url https://plnkr.co/edit/2rtX5cueg2hlzmztUbkH?p=preview

Need any option/property to download the chart as image

**Code**`

```
export class App {

    //single: any[];
    multi: any[];

    // Size to be displayed 
    view: any[] = [1000, 400];

    // options

    showXAxis = true;
    showYAxis = true;
    gradient = false;
    showLegend = true;
    showXAxisLabel = true;
    xAxisLabel = 'Hour';
    showYAxisLabel = true;
    yAxisLabel = 'Days';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked specifically at that chart component, but I assume that it's drawing the chart to a canvas. If you can get a reference to the canvas, you generate an image from it. See [Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)